# Data on cable lubricant

Tags: cable, lubricant, preventative-maintenance

Chain lubrication is a popular topic. Perhaps for this reason, it is possible to find data for chain friction and chain lubrication. Some of the results of the research are quite interesting. I'm speaking of results such as these:

https://www.ceramicspeed.com/media/3505/velonews-friction-facts-chain-lube-tests-combined.pdf

I have a cargo bike which uses cables for steering. This application is really demanding on the cables, probably more than braking which puts the cables through less motion than steering does. So I really want to lubricate the cables with the best lube. Is there any research like this, with real empirical data, which compares different cable lubricants instead?

Comment: Isn't there a lubricant and a lubricating procedure recommended by the maker of said bike since this also represents a road-safety issue?

Comment: I am the maker of said bike.

Comment: Let’s rephrase @Carel’s comment: aren’t lubrication procedures recommended by the manufacturers of the *components*? For Shimano’s top 3 road groups, the cable sets come pre-lubricated, so they say don’t add any. (Also, those have some sort of polymer coating on the cables)

Comment: @WeiwenNg My experience with polymer-coated cables is they're great until the polymer starts to wear and peel off the cable - then they just plain suck and wind up having to be replaced a lot faster than standard uncoated stainless steel cables.  When I was riding heavily I'd be lucky to get a month or two out of them.

Comment: Another possibility is that you're seeing the consequences of the design choice of using cables.  It could be that a push rod or chain drive steering would be more resilient, at the cost of more weight and complexity.

Answer (score 4):

This is not "data" on chain lubrication, rather just a general note, but contrary to some opinion on this subject, some components maker do suggest to use a special grease on some of their brake or shift cable. Example from [Shimano's doc](https://si.shimano.com/api/publish/storage/pdf/en/dm/BR0003/DM-BR0003-09-ENG.pdf) (suggesting use of [Y04180000 cable grease](https://www.google.com/search?q=Y04180000)).

Comment: Which is a silicon grease. I’m surprised noone else mentioned it, well done.

Answer (score 2):

A couple of thoughts:

1. Manufacturers would have the best information about this.  If they are using another company's product, such as when Trek installs Shimano brakes, they generally follow the original producer's guidance; in my example, Trek will generally follow Shimano's advice.  When they vary from it, it's because they have considerable engineering expertise of their own, as well as direct contact with their supplier, and can make very well-informed diversions from that advice to suit their particular situation.  The upshot?  Do what the manufacturer says.
2. What if the manufacturer doesn't say?  That's more complicated, I suppose.  Cables in general are susceptible to temperature- and friction-related degradation in performance.  A lubricant that avoids those pitfalls is advisable.  One option is powdered molybdenum disulfide (possibly blended with PTFE powder), applied minimally.  It is a powder, and so does not become more viscous with lower temperature.  It also does a great job of reducing friction.

In the end, though, if your ability to steer depends on cables, and you are noticing reduced performance from the cables, they should be replaced.  I recognize that this does not meet your request for data, but I hope it has some value nonetheless.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I've used the same lube on my cables as I have on my chain. In my area, Tennessee, it was suggested that I use a dry wax based lube and it's worked for a little over a year now.

You'd apply it the same way and be mindful to wipe of the excess so as to avoid dust and gunk build up. I also have watched quite a few videos from ParkTool on Youtube and they've been really informative.